# Hopf fibration Poincaré surface of section

Tags: differential-equations

How would it be possible to plot in *Mathematica* the Poincaré surface of section, say on the plane y=0 of the streamlines of the so-called Hopf fibration which has a tangent vector field with components

```
u_x = (2A/d^2)*(x*z - r*y);
u_y = (2A/d^2)*(r*x + y*z);
u_z = (A/d^2)*(r^2 - x^2 - y^2 + z^2);
```

where

```
d=r^2+x^2+y^2+z^2;
```

and $A=const.$ and $r=const.$

The differential equations whose solutions are the trajectories of the Hopf-fibration are

```
x'[t] = u_x/Abs[u];
y'[t] = u_y/Abs[u];
z'[t] = u_z/Abs[u];
```

Comment: What is `u` on the right hand sides of the differential equations?

Comment: What are the initial conditions?

Comment: @MMM u is the tangent vector with components u_x, u_y, u_z. The initial conditions are x(0)=x_0, y(0)=y_0, z(0)=z_0, with x_0, y_0, z_0 constants.

Comment: So, you meant to say that `x'[t]=u_x/Abs[u_x]`? Your system of differential equations is coupled nonlinear one, thus, we need specific numerical values for `x0, y0` and `z0` to be able to find a numerical solution.

Comment: @MMM no `x'[t]=u_x/Abs[u]` where `(u^2=u_x^2+u_y^2+u_z^2)` is the correct equation. The numerical values for the initial conditions can be random, the problem is how to built the algorithm.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/RotatingTheHopfFibration/) or [this](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/HopfFibrationOfTheThreeSphere/) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can plot the components of `u` by using `ContourPlot3D` like this

```
A = 1; r = 1; d = r^2 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2;
ContourPlot3D[{(2 A/d^2)*(x*z - r*y), (2 A/d^2) (r*x + y*z), (A/
     d^2)*(r^2 - x^2 - y^2 + z^2)}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 
  3}]
```

[image]

For the above plot, I took random values for $A$ and $r$.

Since your system of differential equation is coupled and nonlinear, so, I will straight away go for `NDSolve`.

```
d = r^2 + x[t]^2 + y[t]^2 + z[t]^2;
ux = (2*A/d^2)*(x[t]*z[t] - r*y[t]);
uy = (2*A/d^2)*(r*x[t] + y[t]*z[t]);
uz = 1/2*(A/d^2)*(r^2 - x[t]^2 - y[t]^2 + z[t]^2);
u = Sqrt[ux^2 + uy^2 + uz^2];
soln = NDSolve[{x'[t] == ux/Abs[u], y'[t] == uy/Abs[u], 
    z'[t] == uz/Abs[u], x[0] == 0, y[0] == 1, z[0] == 0}, {x, y, 
    z}, {t, 0, 50}];
```

Finally ploting the results as a 3D,

```
ParametricPlot3D[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. soln, {t, 0, 50}, 
 PlotRange -> All, MaxRecursion -> 8, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, ViewPoint -> Front]
```

[image]

**Edit**

In responce to your xz-plane view comment, @J.M. suggested `ParametericPlot`,

```
ParametricPlot[{x[t], z[t]} /. soln, {t, 0, 250}, PlotRange -> All, 
 MaxRecursion -> 8, AxesLabel -> {"x", "z"}]
```

[image]

For set of different initial conditions, you can do something like this,

```
sol[x0_?NumericQ, y0_?NumericQ, z0_?NumericQ] :=NDSolve[{x'[t] == ux/Abs[u], y'[t] == uy/Abs[u], z'[t] == uz/Abs[u],
         x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0, z[0] == z0}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 250}];
    ParametricPlot3D[
     Evaluate[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. sol[#, #, #] & /@ 
       Range[2, 5, .1]], {t, 0, 250}, PlotRange -> All, MaxRecursion -> 8,
      AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

[image]

Comment: if we multiply the component u_z by 1/2 we obtain a fibration. How can we take the map of this plot on the x-z plane?

Comment: Also for different initial values we take different curves. How can we depict those curves for various initial points in the same plot?

Comment: @DK13 To view just xz-plane use this `ViewPoint -> Front` and to label the axes use `AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}`

Comment: ...or just use `ParametricPlot[]` on the `x` and `z` components.

Comment: My mistake, I want to take the piercings of the curve with tha y=0 plane (the Poincare map). I suppose that one has to use the routine `WhenEven[]`...

Comment: @DK13 You are always welcome.